# Can a group of PCs act like a local pool?

Tags: mining-pools, miners, pool-mining

I know what pools are for, they combine many nodes power to mine a block quicker but these are cloud pools.

Could a group of PCs or mining rigs which are at the same network act like a pool and combine their powers to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but these are cloud pools.

Not always no. A pool doesn't need to run in the "cloud".

> Could a group of PCs or mining rigs which are at the same network act like a pool and combine their powers to mine?

A group of PCs all solo mining to the same wallet address is almost exactly the same thing as that group of PCs mining to a pool running on the local network.

With tens, hundreds or thousands on PCs on a network, running a local network pool makes much more sense, as it:

- ensures there is no nonce overlap
- reduces traffic
- reduces load

A mining proxy (like XMRig Proxy), also accomplishes the same.

Comment: I see, so you mean I don't need to create a local pool to mine into monero blockchain?

Comment: Correct. You do not need a local pool to mine Monero.